# Yii: zii.widgets.CDetailView - declare attrs in model or just in arguments of the widget?

Tags: yii

I have a model (let's call it `M`). This model has a relation (let's call it `R`) to an other model (`X`).

By default Gii generates the code which shows `R` as a numeric ID (primary key in the DB). I want to show it as a hyperlink.

I consider two ways to do it with zii.widgets.CDetailView:

- provide extra arguments to `$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView')`;
- define method `getHyperlink()` in my model class and refer to the property as `->hyperlink`.

Which of these two ways is better?

The first way may require duplicate code (say in `index.php` with zii.widgets.CListView generated by Gii).

The second way requires `attributeLabels()` with new attribute `hyperlink` which would have the same title as an other (non-hyperlinked numeric) attribute. So I write the same title two times.

So, what of these two variants is better?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would think that the second method using the model would be better due to being more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

If you decide that you wanted to use the hyperlink inside of another view, then you would not have to redefine the logic with extra arguments to `$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView');`

Comment: Except for the fact that you are now adding view code to your model, which is supposed to be separate from the view ... :-)

Comment: @acorncom That's a good point. I suppose an alternative to the two methods could be to use a [CLinkColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkColumn), and configure its `url` attribute with a `getUrl()` method from the model.

Comment: yes, the `getUrl()` method could work, but should your model really be URL-aware?  Seems like your models should be as view/route agnostic as possible.  I'd probably just end up with two CLinkColumn setups which, while not ideal, keeps you from diving into a model just to figure out what URL you're sending people to ...

Comment: @acorncom Well, depending on how often you link to the model, redefining the url creation logic in each view could be painful if the URL ever needs to change. Perhaps another component could be created for centralizing the URL resolution code.

Comment: true, although what's lovely about Yii is that the URL resolution code is already built-in with the routing system.  As long as you use a basic setup like <controller>/<action>, you can totally change your URLs in the future using the routing system.  Things are built with the `getUrl` portion of the CUrlManager.  It's really slick ;-)

Comment: @acorncom True. I suppose I meant to say if you decide to change your <controller>/<action> for the model, rather than the URL itself.